# Telegram Bot: bot stops when more than 20 users use concurently

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a bot which takes some simple information similar to filling a form. It works fine for 2 to 5 users but it suddenly stops receiving and sending messages when number of users reach upto 20. There is no error in logs. It just stops. I want to ask is there any limit to number of messages per second Telegram bot can respond to? Can this be Telegram bot issue or should I debug my code starting from 1 user and gradually increase number of users to see if something appears.
Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: I found the same information as in Mohammad Hamedani's answer after 30 seconds of Googling. It would have been quicker for you to do that than to post your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on telegram documentation, if telegram limits occured, telegram return 429 response code.

[Telegram limits](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this) are:

- one message per second in one chat
- to 30 messages per second for multiple chats

You can use [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) or [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) function to prevent telegram limitation.

```
sleep(1); //sleep script for one second
usleep(500000); //sleep script for half-second - 0.5*1000000
```

Comment: Thanks I will check and come back to you.